# How to remove the installed csd file from cloudera manager

Tags: service, installation, cloudera

Trying to install spark2 2.0.0.cloudera2 to a offline CDH 5.11 system. Copied SPARK2_ON_YARN-2.1.0.cloudera2.jar, which is a WRONG version, to the /opt/cloudera/csd directory of the name node server, as per the online instruction page. Due to offline, the installation failed as expected. Then copy the SPARK2-2.0.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.118100-el7.parcel and its sha file to /opt/cloudera/parcel-repo directory and install, dispatch and activate the service.

While starting the service from the console, below error is seen:

- The CSD version (2.1.0.cloudera2) is not compatible with the current
- Spark 2 version (2.0.0.cloudera2). Either update your CSD or
- make sure you have the correct Spark version installed and
- activated.

Remove the service, and then remove the csd and parcel file, then restart the CM. Re-install the parcel and try to restart the service, the same error is reported.

Please let me know where and how to remove the csd file residue?

Also tried to stop spark before start the spark2, the same error is seen.

could this error the real error since the erroneous csd file is removed from /opt/cloudera/csd?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved by searching the web.

Remove the csd file won't clean the version, restart the service, "cloudera-scm-server", from the management host is also required. Please refer https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_mc_addon_services.html for detail